# Select data where date is this week?

Tags: mysql

How can I limit my SQL to contain data only for this week? (monday to sunday)

Thought of:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE timestamp >= timestamp - INTERVAL 7 DAY && DAYOFWEEK(timestamp-INTERVAL 7 DAY) > 2
```

But something is not right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM log 
WHERE yearweek(curdate()) = yearweek(timestamp)
```

[YEARWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)